# Can't find missing alias: every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

Here is two simple tables

```
CREATE TABLE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR(
    VEN_CODE INT,
    VEN_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    VEN_STATUS INT
);
CREATE TABLE `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT (
  P_CODE INT,
  P_DECSRIOTION VARCHAR(20),
  P_PRICE INT,
  P_COUNT INT,
  V_CODE INT references VENDOR(VEN_CODE)
);
```

I want to increment `VEN_STATUS` for every `VENDOR` who have more than 15 `PRODUCT`'s. Here is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR AS P) 
SET VEN_STATUS = VEN_STATUS + 1 
WHERE VEN_CODE IN (
SELECT VEN_CODE FROM `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR AS N
    WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT AS T WHERE V_CODE = VEN_CODE) > 15
);
```

But I have this errror: **every derived table must have its own alias**. I don't know where I am wrong because every `SELECT` has it's own alias.

UPD1: With help in comments I found wrong `UPDATE` syntax and change it to this

```
UPDATE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR
SET VEN_STATUS = VEN_STATUS + 1 
WHERE VEN_CODE IN (
    SELECT VEN_CODE FROM `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR AS N
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT AS T 
            WHERE V_CODE = VEN_CODE) > 15
);
```

But I still have a problem:

> 18:09:59  UPDATE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR SET VEN_STATUS = VEN_STATUS + 1 
>   WHERE VEN_CODE IN ( SELECT VEN_CODE FROM `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR AS N 
>   WHERE (     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT AS T WHERE
>   V_CODE = VEN_CODE) > 15 ) Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target
>   table 'VENDOR' for update in FROM clause  0.000 sec

Comment: `UPDATE (SELECT * FROM `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR AS P) SET ...` ???? Check the manual for the syntax of an UPDATE query

Comment: Also always show us all the error message, dont summarise as you will often miss something relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly you right, but `UPDATE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR
SET...` dosn't work anyway

Comment: In what way **does it not work** Please be specific and show any error messages IN your Question

Comment: @RiggsFolly question is updated in according with your request for error message

Comment: Make it "more than 4 product" and see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `UPDATE (SELECT....`. You should specify the name of the table you updating. You can simplify the query a bit:

```
UPDATE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR
SET VEN_STATUS = VEN_STATUS + 1 
WHERE VEN_CODE IN (
    SELECT V_CODE 
    FROM `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT
    GROUP BY V_CODE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 15
);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I want to write query without `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

Comment: @AlexIdest, Why? It will be more complex and slower.

Comment: it's because I am trying to do it as simple for me as I can. But after a few minutes full understanding of your query comes to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE `shopdb_1.0`.VENDOR v
    SET VEN_STATUS = VEN_STATUS + 1 
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM `shopdb_1.0`.PRODUCT p
           WHERE v.V_CODE = p.VEN_CODE
          ) > 15;
```

This would likely have good performance with an index on `product(V_CODE)`.